# Double slit experiment with detector and experimenter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, observers, double-slit-experiment, wavefunction-collapse

In the double slit experiment we have particles which travel through two slits and then hit a final wall/detector.

We can perform the experiment with or without an extra detector at the slits which measures through which of the slits it travels.

Also, a human experimenter can choose to look at the results of this extra detector or not.

Hence I see three possible experiments:

A no which-way detector at the slits

B a which-way detector at the slits but no human experimenter looks at the results of this detector. The results are deleted afterwards.

C a which-way detector at the slits and a human experimenter looks at the results of this detector.

Which of these experiments give different result patterns at the final wall/detector?

My guess is that A and B give different results, and that B and C give the same results. But I am not sure, and I don’t know if people have actually tried options B and C seperately.

Comment: Yes, experimenter does not matter, and there is no difference between B) and C).

Comment: The EM field sees both slits, the particle (electron) or energy(photon) only passes one slit.  The EM field guides the path taken, the EM field is already interacting with the excited electron in the atom/electrode long before it begins its journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer:

**A)** Interference pattern from two slits

**B)** It depends on what you mean by "the results are deleted afterwards," but unless the information is destroyed in a very specific and absolute/quantum way, the interference pattern will be destroyed.

**C)** No interference pattern

## Long answer:

If a measurement is made that in principle could tell you which slit the particle went through, then there is no interference pattern *even if nobody ever learns the outcome of the measurements.*

However, it is possible to destroy the information about which slit the particle went through in a way that the intereference reappears. This is called a "[quantum erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment)."

For instance, if a beam of light is used and polarizers with opposite orientations are placed at each slit (say that filters out right handed vs left handed [circularly polarized light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization)), then detecting which polarization state tells you which slit the light went through and the two beams will not interefere, whether or not the polarization and thus which slit is actually measured or not!

However, if you now place a [linear polarizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Linear_polarizers) before the detector, the which slit information is *erased* and you will see an interference pattern again. In fact, even if you choose to add this slit after the light has gone through the slits you still see the interence pattern. Such an experiment has actually been done and is called a "[delayed-choice quantum erasure experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser)."

Comment: In your answer, it seems possible that options B and C give a different result when the which-way information is quantum erased. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If the which-way information is quantum erased then there is interference as in option A. If the which-way information is NOT erased, then there is NO intereferece like in option C.

Comment: But what happens if the information is erased in option C? Which means that the human experimenter looks at the results and then the device quantum erases the measurement result

Comment: @Riemann If "which-slot" info became available to experimenter the interference picture is destroyed. Period. The experimenter may read the info carefully or throw it into a bucket without looking into it, it does not matter.

Comment: Then options B and C are different with the following extra conditions:

Comment: Option B - the which-slot detector quantum deletes the data afterwards and hence there is a interference pattern

Comment: Option C - the which-slot detector also quantum deletes the data afterwards, but before that a human experimenter checks these data. Now there is no interference pattern

Comment: @Riemann I guess you don't understand what info can be quantum-erased. Definitely not the info that is available to experimenter. Informally, only the info "under the quantum hood" can be "quantum-erased".

Comment: Ok, that’s clear. Thank you

Comment: @Riemann if you mess with the particle after the slits then the effect of the 2 slits is effectively neutralized and there is NO pattern.   It does not matter if the which slit detector is observed by human or not.

Comment: @Riemann: In order to quantum erase the information after learning about it would mean performing treating the person (and the rest of the environment) as a very large quantum system and performing the quantum erasure on the person (and environment) as a whole. In principle this does not violate the laws of quantum and has even been used in thought experiments (https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-07-08-498). However, in practice this would require a god-like level of experimental control over the world that is likely infeasable.

Comment: Hypothetically we can consider tractors as particles in double-slot experiment, but I strongly doubt that such experiment is really possible.